# programming - How to convert text value to a field

Tags: apex

In Object Alpha, I have two fields 
Field currentDate__c = Date.today().format(); (say) and field relevantfield__c= “Partner__r. lmn_currentDate_c” (this field value changes and specifies when this currentDate__c should be updated )and object partner is a lookup field on object alpha
When currentDate__c get updated I have to get text field value from relevantfield__c and update that field. How to do this I am stuck. Any inputs?
say alpha a;
I tried to use a.get (’Partner__r. lmn_currentDate_c’); to update trigger.new to update the list it is gives me error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to "follow the path" by using the appropriate methods..Something like the following:

```
public Object getValueFromPath(sobject record, string path) {
  String[] parts = path.split('\\.');
  while(parts.size() > 1 && record != null) {
    record = record.getsObject(parts.remove(0));
  }
  return record == null? null: record.get(parts[0]);
}
```

Comment: Should be `record.get(parts[0])`.

Comment: Also, returning `record` instead of explicitly `null` might introduce exception paths.

Comment: @AdrianLarson Thanks, I was mobile, fixed the typo. Also, null is null. That said, I was also mobile, so one less null was less painful to do in the moment .

Comment: If you declare a null SObject and try to cast it to a String, you will get an exception, no?

Comment: @AdrianLarson Nope. A null is a null. The trick here is that we're upcasting to an Object, which we can then downcast to any type. Try this out: `Object a; Integer b = (Integer)a; String c = (String)a; sObject d = (sObject)a; Account e = (Account)a;` Or, even more fun: `Integer a; String b; Object c = a; Object d = b; System.assertEquals(b, d);` Nulls are only dangerous in terms of NullPointerException.

Comment: You have a failure path here, not sure why you don't see it. `SObject foo; String bar = (String)foo;` yields an error: `Incompatible types since an instance of SObject is never an instance of String`.

Comment: @AdrianLarson because that can't happen... I'm returning an Object type, not sObject type, and a null is still a null. Try writing this out and experimenting. There **is** an error that can happen, just not the one you're thinking of.